# Should I reformat this sentence?

Tags: sentence, commas, syntactic-analysis, semicolons

I kind of feel like the first comma in the sentence below should be a semi-colon.  Does anything else in there read funny?

> As you’ll see in my enclosed resume, I
>   have the educational background,
>   professional experience and track
>   record for which you are searching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go with:

> As you’ll see in my enclosed resume, I have the educational background, professional experience and track record you are looking for.

- The clauses in this sentence are not "independent enough" to warrant a semicolon.
- The "for which" sounds a bit complicated.
- "[look for](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/look%20for)" (make sure, ascertain, anticipate or expect) is better than "a [search](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/search)"

Comment: How about "track record you seek"?

Answer (score 7):

There's a simple rule regarding semicolons: they are used instead of full stops. Can you put a full stop in this sentence? No. Hence, no semicolon!

Answer (score 0):

> I kind of feel like the first comma in the sentence below should be a semi-colon.

You think it should be

> > As you’ll see in my enclosed resume**;** I have the educational background, professional experience and track record for which you are searching.

? No, that is definitely wrong, that should not be a semicolon.